# Unable to redirect the output values of outputs.tf file to a different file on azure-pipelines.yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to redirect the output values of outputs.tf file to a different file from the azure-pipelines.yaml. To achieve that I am using an AzurePowershell task on the pipeline yaml. PFB.

```
- stage: terraform_output
dependsOn: ["infrastructure_creation"]
jobs:
- job: output
pool: Ansible
steps:
- task: charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform-installer.TerraformInstaller@0
inputs:
terraformVersion: '1.2.3'
- task: TerraformTaskV3@3
inputs:
provider: 'azurerm'
command: 'init'
workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VM'
environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'xxxxxx'
backendServiceArm: 'xxxxxx'
backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'xxxxxxxx'
backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'xxxxxx'
backendAzureRmContainerName: 'xxxxx'
backendAzureRmKey: 'xxxxxxxx'
- task: TerraformTaskV3@3
inputs:
provider: 'azurerm'
command: 'output'
workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VM'
environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'xxxxxxxx'
backendServiceArm: 'xxxxxxxx'
backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'xxxxxxx'
backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'xxxxxxx'
backendAzureRmContainerName: 'xxxx'
backendAzureRmKey: 'xxxxxxx'
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
inputs:
azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxx'
ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
Inline: |
(TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach(
(
($prop.Value.value)") }
Write-Output 
(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ansible-roles\inventory\output.json
workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/VM'
preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '9.5.0'
```

But this isn't working. Getting the below error.

```
Exception: /home/vsts-agent/ansibleadoagent/_work/_tasks/AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62/5.218.0/InitializeAz.ps1:38
Line |
38 | throw ("Could not find the module Az.Accounts with given version. …
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Could not find the module Az.Accounts with given version. If the module
| was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure Pipelines task
| agent.
```

We are using hosted agent.
Az.Accounts module was properly installed & the agents were restarted.

To check if the script is correct or not I tried by echoing "Hello-World" to the required file. Even though the stage was successful, the output.json file never got modified/updated.

```
Inline: |
Write-Output "Hello-World" > $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\ansible-roles\inventory\output.json
```

Need help in resolving this particular issue.

Comment: Can you add Import-Az.Account at the start of your Powershell script task?

Comment: Even doing that is not helping.

Comment: Is the same powershell script running successfully locally in your devops host agent?

Comment: I have no ways to test that locally since I will be using the Terraform output values that gets generated in runtime. The above code is part of the complete pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are working with ansible and are trying to output a json file that ansible will use. I have done this before. You can do this right from inside your Terraform code without publishing outputs and trying to parse it with powershell. Simply generate a local object in Terraform with the same object structure you want in JSON/YAML and then use the file provider to save a file where the contents are set to the jsonencode() method with your local object inside. This is a much simpler solution.

By the way ansible also supports yaml inventory files so you could also use the yamlencode method. This is the approach I use when integrating ansible with Terraform.

Then you can use Azure Devops copyfiles task or publish pipeline artifact to pass the file between jobs. I've done a video on this with td plan files but the same approach could be used with a file generated by the file provider.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. But here I am only using the Pool Agent named "Ansible". Although in the larger picture I would be using this terraform output values to replace in an already present ansible inventory file, for which I have written a simple bash script. For this current scenario, I am only trying to redirect my tf output values to a file, which in turn would be called by the bash script. But, I would really love to go through the solution you provided. Do you have the video link to share with me?